# Android Gradle build script found

Tags: android-studio

When downloading code for a project from GitHub I get "Android Gradle build script found". How do I get the project to compile on my device.

I tried adding a configuration but could not specify the module. It does not allow me to select a device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't download the project directly from github, you need to clone it, to do this, in the project repository in github click `code` than copy the link that ends with `git` ,  in Android studio head to `File->New->Project from Version Control`  and past the link there, this way you will clone the project with it's original configuration, and you wont need to do much configuration.